# how to call bean's function with param in jsp

Tags: function, jsp, parameter-passing, javabeans

com.app.util.LangSupport has function getJsonString(String locale) to return a json string by locale.

In JSP how to pass the locale from the request's param to the bean's getJsonString(String locale) to get the json string back so that the string could be used by other javascript in the session?

will this work? if not what is the right way to do it?

```
app.lang_json = <%=theBean.getJsonString(<%=request.getParameter("lang_locale")%>)%>;
```

in JSP it has the bean

```
<jsp:useBean id="theBean" class="com.app.util.Support" />

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var app = ${theBean.init};
    app.lang_json = <%=theBean.getJsonString('<%=request.getParameter("lang_locale")%>')%>;
<body>
......
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

seems this will work. If anyone knows better way please update Thanks!

```
<jsp:useBean id="theBean" class="com.app.util.Support" />

<%! String strLocale; %>

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var app = ${theBean.init};
    <% strLocale=request.getParameter("lang_locale"); %>
    app.lang_json=<%=theBean.getJsonString(strLocale) %>;

<body>
......
</body>
</html>
```